# I work with github api on redux-toolkit(rtk-query) and have a problem

Tags: redux-toolkit, rtk-query, react-tsx

**Uncaught Error: Warning: Middleware for RTK-Query API at reducerPath "github/api" has not been added to the store.
You must add the middleware for RTK-Query to function correctly!**

```
import {configureStore} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import {githubApi} from "./github/github.api";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    [githubApi.reducerPath]: githubApi.reducer
  },
})
```

```
import {createApi, fetchBaseQuery} from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

export const githubApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'github/api',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: 'https://api.github.com/'
  }),
  endpoints: build => ({
    searchUsers: build.query<any, string>({
      query: (search: string) => ({
        url: `search/users`,
        params: {
          q: search
        }
      })
    })
  })
})

export const {useSearchUsersQuery} = githubApi
```

```
import React from "react";
import {useSearchUsersQuery} from "../store/github/github.api";

export function HomePage() {
  const {isLoading, isError, data} = useSearchUsersQuery('anyname')

  return (
     <div>Home</div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's literally what it says - in your `configureStore` call, you skipped adding the RTK Query middleware.

```js
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    [githubApi.reducerPath]: githubApi.reducer
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(githubApi.middleware),
})
```